# Responsive src video code shopify

Tags: html, css, video, shopify, responsive

Here is what I have

Here is the link to the page
https://www.bonmarcheonline.com/pages/about-us/#our-story

Comment: Add `#illusion { max-width: 100%; }`

Answer (score 0):

Restrict the width of your video to 100%.

```
#illusion {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```